# Return a JSON object in the body of a HTTPS response

Tags: php, json, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, actions-on-google

I have a OAUTH 2.0 Server, and i have succesfully implemented it up to the last level using **PHP**

Reference Link : https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow

## However, im am on the Last Step now which says

--->  Return the following JSON object in the body of the HTTPS response

```
 {
 token_type: "bearer",
 access_token: "ACCESS_TOKEN",
 refresh_token: "REFRESH_TOKEN",
 expires_in: SECONDS_TO_EXPIRATION
 }
```

## I have done the following

```
$json = array(
'token_type:' => "bearer",
'access_token:' => $ACCESS_TOKEN,
'refresh_token:' => $REFRESH_TOKEN,
'expires_in:' => '3600'

);
  $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
  echo $jsonstring;
  die();
```

In which `$ACCESS_TOKEN` and `$REFRESH_TOKEN` and two variables containing the necessary information. 
My Question is how do i return the 'JSON object in the body of the HTTPS response: '?

Would mean a lot if anyone can help me figure this out
Thanks in Advance!

Please visit this site, and see you might understand what i'm trying to do then :) 
 https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow

Comment: Are you getting an error when you test it? What is causing you to believe you have a problem? Please update your question with any additional information about what you're seeing.

Comment: It says that i need to return a JSON object in the body of the HTTPS response. Im quite sure how to do this :/

Comment: ive created a json file but how do i return it in the body of the HTTPS response?

Comment: That is from the documentation. Have you tested your code to see what it does?

Comment: Yeah, when i do it from my end meaning i pass the authentication code from the url it succesfully prints the Access token and refresh token but when i do it from the google aouth play ground i get an error PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: client in

Comment: Please update your question to show exactly what error messages you're getting.

Comment: Im not getting a error message. I just dont know how to return a JSON obejct in a http response

Comment: I'm confused. If you're not getting an error message, what did you mean when you said "i get an error PHP Notice: Undefined variable: client in"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of your action appears to be correct. Sending JSON as the body requires two steps.

First, you must set the content-type header to indicate the body is JSON. You **must** do this *before any other data, including blank lines, are output*. Having this right after the PHP header on the page is probably good practice to make sure nothing else included generates this. This header is done as something like

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application/json");
```

The rest of your code looks correct. Sending a "JSON Object" means sending a specifically formatted text representation of the data. That formatting is done through json_encode().

```
$json = array(
  'token_type:' => "bearer",
  'access_token:' => $ACCESS_TOKEN,
  'refresh_token:' => $REFRESH_TOKEN,
  'expires_in:' => '3600'
);
$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;
```

Comment: After adding the header is works like a Charm! Thanks